# Store : Update order status on checkout submit

Tags: expresso-store, status, orders

I want to update the status of an order to **processing** once the checkout form has been submitted.

Looking through the dev docs: https://www.expresso.com/docs/extension_hooks.html

One of these two hooks fit the bill:

- store_payment_request_start
- store_payment_request_end

These are called when the order is processed by a payment provider - however, if I use a discount code for 100% off (ie, a free order) then these hooks aren't called (which does makes sense to me - I'm assuming the order isn't pinged to the payment provider as there is no payment to make).

Anyway, I can't see any further hooks that I can use to accomplish this status change, is anyone aware of way I can change the order status on a checkout submission?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an iterim order status between being marked as 'New' when the user comes back from the payment gateway after a successful payment?

Otherwise in the Store settings there are 'Order Statuses' with the default being 'New' once an order has been processed/submitted, but theres no reason why you can't add a new default status of 'Processing' instead. Then you could have another status of 'Shipped' so you can assign that status when a particular order has been sent out.

If you have any existing orders you might not be able edit the default 'New' status as it's already assigned to those orders.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I am looking for an interim status. Literally as soon as the checkout form has been submitted. I've looked at the custom order status in the CP and I can see how to set these (either manually or through hooks) but without the right hook I can't set this 'processing' status.